# Mean Reciprocal Rank with GBM in R

Tags: boosting

Let's say I'm optimizing [MRR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_reciprocal_rank) with a GBM in R:

```
library(gbm)
generate.data <- function(N) {

  # create query groups, with an average size of 25 items each
  num.queries <- floor(N/25)
  query <- sample(1:num.queries, N, replace=TRUE)

  # X1 is a variable determined by query group only
  query.level <- runif(num.queries)
  X1 <- query.level[query]

  # X2 varies with each item
  X2 <- runif(N)

  # X3 is uncorrelated with target
  X3 <- runif(N)

  # The target
  Y <- X1 + X2

  # Add some random noise to X2 that is correlated with
  # queries, but uncorrelated with items

  X2 <- X2 + scale(runif(num.queries))[query]

  # Add some random noise to target
  SNR <- 5 # signal-to-noise ratio
  sigma <- sqrt(var(Y)/SNR)
  Y <- Y + runif(N, 0, sigma)
  Y <- ifelse(Y>median(Y), 1, 0)

  data.frame(Y, query=query, X1, X2, X3)
}

set.seed(10)
data.train <- generate.data(1000)
gbm.mrr <- gbm(Y~X1+X2+X3,          # formula
                data=data.train,     # dataset
                distribution=list(   # loss function:
                  name='pairwise',   # pairwise
                  metric="mrr",     # ranking metric:
                  max.rank=1,
                  group='query'),    # column indicating query groups
                n.trees=2000,        # number of trees
                shrinkage=0.005,     # learning rate
                interaction.depth=3, # number per splits per tree
                bag.fraction = 0.5,  # subsampling fraction
                train.fraction = 1,  # fraction of data for training
                n.minobsinnode = 10, # minimum number of obs for split
                keep.data=TRUE,      # store copy of input data in model
                cv.folds=5,          # number of cross validation folds
                verbose = FALSE,     # don't print progress
                n.cores = 1)         # use a single core

best.iter.mrr <- gbm.perf(gbm.mrr, method='cv')
title('Training of pairwise model with mrr metric')
```

(Code [adapted from here](http://gradientboostedmodels.googlecode.com/svn-history/r68/pkg/demo/pairwise.R))

This produces the following plot, where the black line is in-sample MRR, and the green line is out-of-sample MRR.  Clearly, GBM is mimizing MRR: it chooses the model with the smallest out-of-sample MRR (~0.3):
[image: RPlot]

I'm confused as to why gbm MINIMIZES mrr.  It's my understanding that a MRR of 1 is perfect (best document is the first result, 1/1=1) and a MRR of close to zero is very bad (e.g. best document is the 1000th result, 1/1000 is close to zero).

Is my understanding of mmr correct?  If so, then why does the gbm package minimize it?